# Access the session in my API spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am developing an API and wanted to test the login method. The spec for the API located in `spec/api/` instead of `spec/controller`. I am using rspec-rails. Now I have a spec like this:

```
describe "/api/login.json", :type => :api do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  context "when called with correct credentials" do
    before(:all) do
      post "/api/v1/passenger/login.json",:email => user.email, :password => user.password
    end

    it "responds with HTTP 200" do
      last_response.status.should == 200
    end

    it "sets the session correctly" do
      session[:user_id].should == user.id # <-- ### Here ###
    end
  end
end
```

It fails. `session` is nil. How do I access the session variable?

I guess I have to include some stuff in my `RSpec.configure` block?

Comment: You might try `request.session`, but I'm not sure if it works.

Comment: `request` is a method defined by `Rack::Test::Methods` which I include in my helper for `:type => :api` tests. It is a method similar to `post` and `get` and requires an URL as parameter. So `request.session` just throws `ArgumentError Exception: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Comment: is Api::LoginController being described higher up on the describe chain? I wonder if ActionController::TestCase::Behavior is being mixed in. can you access controller.session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After approx. 200 hours of googling, I found an answer myself.

It boils down to these magic words:

```
module FoobarHelper
  def session
    last_request.env['rack.session']
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.include FoobarHelper, :type => :api
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If your sessions are enabled, I guess you can get it with `env['rack.session']`.

I will also recommend you this tut http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails
Using pry has many advantages, you can write `binding.pry` in your spec and debug it